# Using the R code `sample` function, take out 10 random samples of 500 observations

Tags: r

Easiest way to do - Using the R code `sample` function, take out 10 random samples of 500 observations from the 10000 rnorm each.  Calculate the mean of each sample.  Then calculate the mean of the sample means and the standard deviation of the sample means.

Comment: What did you try to do this?  What is the problem with your code?

Comment: I provided an answer, but in general we do request that you do some initial research on your own and show where you ran into a problem. If it's a code problem we require a reproducible example if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
#take out 10 random samples of 500 observations from the 10000 rnorm each. 

s0 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)
s1 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)
s2 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)
s3 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)
s4 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)
s5 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)
s6 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)
s7 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)
s8 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)
s9 <- sample(rnorm(10000),500)

#Calculate the mean of each sample. 
c(mean(s0),mean(s1), mean(s2), mean(s3),
  mean(s4), mean(s5), mean(s6), mean(s7),
  mean(s8), mean(s9))
```

> ```
>  [1]  0.028727024 -0.017773740 -0.022705430 -0.001933892  0.045273423  0.009788866  0.004833384  0.018486670  0.007363636  0.017806898
> ```

```
#Then calculate the mean of the sample means 
mean(c(mean(s0),mean(s1), mean(s2), mean(s3),
       mean(s4), mean(s5), mean(s6), mean(s7),
       mean(s8), mean(s9))
)
```

> [1] 0.008986684

```
# standard deviation
sd(c(mean(s0),mean(s1), mean(s2), mean(s3),
       mean(s4), mean(s5), mean(s6), mean(s7),
       mean(s8), mean(s9))
)
```

> [1] 0.02037087

Answer (score 0):

Use `replicate` to repeat the `sample/rnorm` calls.

```
set.seed(1435)   # Make it reproducible

r <- replicate(10, sample(rnorm(1e4), 500))
(m <- colMeans(r))
#[1]  0.058202386  0.013195277 -0.031991121  0.026903820 -0.008564268
#[6] -0.017718631  0.001395289  0.032600240 -0.045317892  0.086021587

(M <- mean(m))
#[1] 0.01147267

(s <- sd(m))
#[1] 0.04068593
```